# Выбор максимального значения строки

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Есть sql запрос

```
SELECT connect_time, auth, duration 
FROM player_analytics 
WHERE auth IN ('" . implode("','", $steam) . "')
```

Нужно доработать его так, чтобы выбирало последние `connect_time` для значений auth
Для общего понимания: база - история входов игрока на сервер а я вывожу список друзей и нужно вывести в таком же порядке как записано в массив $steam. connect_time записывается в unix формате. Помогите пожалуйста, я уже запарился

Comment: `ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(auth, implode("','", $steam))`

Comment: @Akina Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result